# Pass paramater to thread's method

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

In this example, I cannot pass a value to the method that is being used to run multiple threads.

```
private void btnStartSingleHost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        new System.Threading.Thread(establishConnection).Start();
}

private void establishConnection()
{
    new SinglePortScan(tbHostIP.Text, int.Parse(nupdHostPort.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nupdHostTimeout.Value.ToString()), ref tbSingleResults).connect();
}
```

What can I do if I want to for example pass value of `i` of the loop to the method that thread is calling?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `ParametrizedThreadStart` delegate instead of the `ThreadStart` delegate.

```
private void btnStartSingleHost_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
        new System.Threading.Thread(establishConnection).Start(i);
}

private void establishConnection(object state)
{
    int i = (int)state;
    // do whatever you want with i here
    new SinglePortScan(tbHostIP.Text, int.Parse(nupdHostPort.Value.ToString()), int.Parse(nupdHostTimeout.Value.ToString()), ref tbSingleResults).connect();
}
```

Comment: This seems pretty straight forward.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is send a struct containing my parameters to the thread.